# Why isnt my class toggling on click Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Not sure what Im doing wrong Ive set up a class toggle in my angular app and it doesnt seem to be working

CHATSIDEBAR.COMPONENT.HTML

```
 <div id="chatsidebarheader">
        <h3><img src="{{meddyLogo}}"> Chat with Meddy</h3>
        <div (click)="userSettingsClass()">
            <img id="usersettingsbutton" src="{{userSettingsLogo}}">
        </div>
</div>
<div id="chatbar-usersettings" [ngClass]="{'usersettings-active': isUserSettingsActive}">
    <h1>User Settings</h1>
</div>
```

CHATSIDEBAR.COMPONENT.TS

```
  isUserSettingsActive = true;

  userSettingsClass(){
      this.isUserSettingsActive = !this.isUserSettingsActive;
  }
```

any help would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your class is predefined it's better to use `[class.usersettings-active]="isUserSettingsActive"` instead of `[ngClass]. [ngClass]` should be used for dynamicaly added classes. However for this problem I think your expression should look like `[ngClass]="isUserSettingsActive ? 'usersettings-active' : ' '"`, please note that empty string `' '`.

Comment: I tried it your way and I got an  Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Conditional expression isUserSettingsActive ? 'usersettings-active : ' '  requires all 3 expressions

Comment: Oh, my bad forgot about ` ' ` should be `isUserSettingsActive ? 'usersettings-active' : ' '  `

Comment: I tried it the first way you said and it worked! thanks a lot is there any documentation that explains that better? thanks again!

Comment: Long time ago I found article about that. I will check angular docs. If I find anything I will post it here. However If I good remember it's about readibility and performance. Because class it's predefined so angular knows what class it will be (there won't be need to evaluate expression to get class name) and it's easier to read it later and know which class would be applied.